# Effect of coloring on emissivity at temperatures below 150C?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity, infrared-radiation

I'm working on Aluminum/Copper heat sink design optimization and came across this thought.

The heat source on which the heat sink is going to be placed is approx 100C. Forced convection is absent, so the heat transfer would be mostly through natural convection and radiation.

I know that anodizing the heat sink will improve it's emissivity. But will the color of the heat sink matter in this temperature range ? That is if don't anodize and just powdercoat the heat sink black in color will the emissivity be improved ? I'm interested only in the radiation aspect and not on the conductivity of the coating.

My understand is that in temperatures below 500C the radiation would mostly be in the IR region, so will the color have any effect in the IR domain?

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure, but will not a powder coat act as a thermal insulator preventing the heat sink from properly radiating?  I was under the naive assumption that anodizing the material helps reduce this insulating issue but perhaps I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

at 150C, heat exchange by emissivity is small compared to conduction. the color of the heat exchange surfaces will not make any difference at that temperature. powder coating will add a layer on top of the aluminum which is not very conductive- better to leave it off.